# Word - Save As object

Tags: vba, save, ms-word

How can I save a Word document as the value in a table? I've tried this and get a "Type mismatch" error:

```
Sub saveas_cell()
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "c:\mydocuments" ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2) & ".doc"
End Sub
```

I've also tried an object reference (`activedocument.table1.("text3")`)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You get an error message because `Table.Cell` does not return a string, but a cell object. Instead, use this:

```
"c:\mydocuments" ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".doc"
```

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211604%28v=office.11%29.aspx).